# Is there a common way to use a text file as a human-readable datastore?

Tags: database

I feel like this problem must have been solved already, and I'm just not finding the answer. Is there an ActiveRecord-like interface for storing data in human-readable text files?

Specifically, I'm thinking about how to split the file-handling / validation portions of [this todo.txt gem](https://github.com/samwho/todo-txt-gem) from the content-parsing portions. Rather than reinvent the wheel, I figured there must be something like SQlite, but that stored values in a custom human-readable format instead. [This is the specification I'm looking to support](https://github.com/ginatrapani/todo.txt-cli/wiki/The-Todo.txt-Format).

Does this exist?

Comment: This really depends on what you mean by human readable, and what you intend on storing. The simple answer would be CSV, or Yaml if you need nesting. But then again, JSON is a human readable text format too :) I suggest you clarify what you want to store exactly, maybe there's a format for that. Also, who would read those files -  and why -  would be useful to know.

Comment: Good point - I'll update my question to clarify the spec I'm building for. (todotxt.com)

Comment: Better :) Yet another question (even though I might not be the one answering) - so if what you're looking for is a `todo.txt` parser specifically, then I guess using the one you referred to does not work for you for some reason. Is it because you want to use another language? If so, which one? Otherwise, I guess your question might be "Is there a parsing framework for language X I can use to parse the `todo.txt` format?" In which case, there are multiple librairies out there than can help you. I hope this will help you get answers :)

Comment: Hmm. I can see how my question is confusing. Perhaps this is really a programming design pattern question. I think I'd really like to know if it's normal to bundle the API with the file handling. It just seems like it's doing a lot of different things in one gem, and that the file stuff should be split out from the list management, todo object handling, etc.